# Highstock: How to disable rangeSelector responsive rule for breaking line between elements?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm trying to develop a very compact chart that displays both `buttons` and `inputSelect` from `rangeSelector` on the same line. Also I have a controller to show/hide stocktools gui interface (this is the source of bug).

Showing gui generates an animation that moves `buttons` to the right, since the distance between both elements are greater than the responsive rule condition (I suppose) they stay on the same line, but when I click to hide the gui an animation triggers and forces `inputSelect` to break a line.

I have tried to use a parameter `chart:{animation:false}`, but for some reason I get the inverse problem. When I click to show the gui interface `inputSelect` breaks a line and when I hide it back it goes back for the same line.

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/bernardo0marques/qw4a1fgz/7/) is a live demo.

I was wondering if I could acces that responsive rule and disable it, but I couldn't find it anywhere in API docs. Also I have tried to use default parameters from `rangeSelector` API but it seems they can't help with that gui animation being triggered.
Any solution for that outcome is valid, I just think this is viable one.

---

## Update

I found this forum thread https://www.highcharts.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=41142. This is a viable workaround, I tried to implement it to make both `input` goes to the right and `buttons` to the left, this way it would be harder for their condition of break line to be met.
Here is the workaround:

```js
chart: {
  events: {
    load: function(){
      let marginRight;
      let marginLeft;
      let marginLeft;
      let this = chart;

      marginRight = chart.marginRight - chart.spacing[1];
      marginLeft = chart.plotLeft + chart.spacing[3];

      chart.update({
        rangeSelector: {
          inputPosition: {
            align: "right",
            x: marginRight,
          },
          buttonPosition: {
            align: "left",
            x: marginLeft,
          }
        }
      });
    }
  },
```

It only worked for the `marginRight` for some reason chart object doesn't have marginLeft property, I was wondering if is there any other way to calculate axis title and labels width to pass as this x offset.

Comment: What do you think about this workaround, where the input is moved more to the right? That adds some extra space between the range selector buttons and the input. Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/hkv4tfwd/ Otherwise, some changes in the core will be needed. Here is a logic responsible for this behaviour: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/blob/master/js/parts/RangeSelector.js#L1211

Comment: This is the workaround I posted on *Update*, but I got it dinamically instead of fixed, using `marginRight` to do it.

Comment: yeah you are right. I think that setting only the input group to the right as much as it is possible is a good solution for this case: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/0npLfxmb/